# Is styled html in a Polymer paper-item possible?

Tags: css, polymer, paper-elements

I am trying to put some rich content inside the items of a `paper-menu`, however this seems not to work as expected (see screenshot below).

What needs to be done to add styled html to the `paper-item`.

The code is here:

```
<style is="custom-style">
    .personItem {
        @apply(--layout-horizontal);
        margin: 16px 16px 0 16px;
        padding: 20px;
        border-radius: 8px;
        background-color: white;
        border: 1px solid #ddd;
    }
    .avatar {
        height: 50px;
        width: 50px;
        border-radius: 25px;
        box-sizing: border-box;
        background-color: #DDD;
    }
    .pad {
        padding: 0 16px;
        @apply(--layout-flex);
        @apply(--layout-vertical);
    }
    .primary {
        font-size: 16px;
        font-weight: bold;
    }
        .dim {
        color: gray;
    }
</style>

<paper-menu-button vertical-align="top" horizontal-align="right" vertical-offset="64">
    <paper-icon-button id="notif" icon="social:notifications" class="dropdown-trigger" alt="menu"></paper-icon-button>
    <paper-menu class="dropdown-content">
        <template is="dom-repeat" items="[[notifications]]" as="item">
            <paper-item>
                <paper-item-body two-line>
                    <!--<div th:inline="none"><iron-icon icon='communication:message'></iron-icon></div>-->
                    <div secondary th:inline="none">
                        <div class="personItem">
                            <iron-image class="avatar" sizing="contain" src="[[item.pic]]"></iron-image>
                            <div class="pad">
                                <div class="primary" th:inline="none">
                                    <span style="float:right;">[[m.date]]</span>
                                    <span>[[m.user]]</span>
                                </div>
                                <div class="dim" th:inline="none">[[m.content]]</div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </paper-item-body>
            </paper-item>
        </template>
    </paper-menu>
</paper-menu-button>
<paper-badge id="badge" for="notif" label="[[number]]"></paper-badge>
```

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This more or less produces what I wanted to achieve:

```
<paper-menu-button>
    <paper-icon-button id="n" icon="social:notifications" class="dropdown-trigger" alt="menu"></paper-icon-button>
    <paper-menu class="dropdown-content">
        <template is="dom-repeat" items="[[notifications]]" as="item">
            <paper-icon-item>
                <iron-icon item-icon class="avatar" sizing="contain" src="/path/to/pic"></iron-icon>
                <paper-item-body two-line>
                    <div>John Doe</div>
                    <div secondary>Hello World</div>
                </paper-item-body>
                <paper-icon-button icon="communication:message"></paper-icon-button>
            </paper-icon-item>
        </template>
    </paper-menu>
</paper-menu-button>
<paper-badge id="badge" for="n" label="[[number]]"></paper-badge>
```